# Error while execute, String won't call into doInbackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, execute

So i'm trying to call a string, the call:

```
EditText EditTextSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
if(!isEmpty(EditTextSearch)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Getting Information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.v("checkText =>", EditTextSearch.getText().toString());
    getComics getComicInfo = new getComics(EditTextSearch.getText().toString(), 1);
    getComicInfo.execute();
}
```

after that i'm calling asynctask

```
class getComics extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{ 
        private String comicName;
        private String comicNameForSearch;
        private int getOptionNumber;
        String jsonString = "";
        String result = ""; 

     getComics(String comicName, int getOptionNumber)
      { 
         Log.v("Check name A =>", comicName); //show name

      }

    //set option for search
    public void SetOptionNumber(int getOptionNumber){   
        this.getOptionNumber = getOptionNumber;

    }

    public int getOptionNumber(){
        return this.getOptionNumber;
    }

    //the data that the user searching for
    public void SetComicName(String comicName){
        this.comicName = comicName; 
    }

    public String GetComicName(){
        return this.comicName;
    }


/*the request to the API, include fixing space and getting information about the main object, data, later on i'll call 
  the object I got to show the the results array */

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {     
        Log.v("is callingB =>", "Yes");
        comicNameForSearch = GetComicName();
        Log.v("check name=>", comicNameForSearch ); // make the app crash
```

anyway, if i'm trying to Log.v, the app crash, what make me think that the DoInBackground doesn't recive the comicName for some reason, guess it because of the execute way, any ideas?

edit: first time going with API so sorry if any dumb problems
the error message:Caused by: java.lang.nullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: Show the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing Assinging the value in `Constructor` so which results in a `NullPointerException`

Change this

```
getComics(String comicName, int getOptionNumber)
  { 
     Log.v("Check name A =>", comicName); //show name
  }
```

into

```
getComics(String comicName, int getOptionNumber)
  { 
     this.comicName = comicName; 
     this.getOptionNumber = getOptionNumber;
     Log.v("Check name A =>", comicName); //show name
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is getting exception because your data in Asynctask  is null which you are printing and passing in doInBackground.

Change you Asynctask to this:

```
class getComics extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{ 
        private String comicName;
        private String comicNameForSearch;
        private int getOptionNumber;
        String jsonString = "";
        String result = ""; 

     getComics(String comicName, int getOptionNumber)
      { 
         this.comicName = comicName;
         this.getOptionNumber = getOptionNumber;
         Log.v("Check name A =>", comicName); //show name

      }

    //set option for search
    public void SetOptionNumber(int getOptionNumber){   
        this.getOptionNumber = getOptionNumber;

    }

    public int getOptionNumber(){
        return this.getOptionNumber;
    }

    //the data that the user searching for
    public void SetComicName(String comicName){
        this.comicName = comicName; 
    }

    public String GetComicName(){
        return this.comicName;
    }


/*the request to the API, include fixing space and getting information about the main object, data, later on i'll call 
  the object I got to show the the results array */

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {     
        Log.v("is callingB =>", "Yes");
        comicNameForSearch = GetComicName();
        Log.v("check name=>", comicNameForSearch ); // make the app crash
```

And Another way is by calling the setter method you have made inside your class like this:

```
  getComics getComicInfo = new getComics(EditTextSearch.getText().toString(), 1);
getComicInfo .SetComicName(EditTextSearch.getText().toString());
getComicInfo .SetOptionNumber(1);
    getComicInfo.execute();
```